# importing assignment into modul re/expected string or buffer Python,

Tags: python

Well I just started learning Python so I don't understand how to make my code correct (Worth to SAY that I learn it from youtube))). What I want from the code is -- if the assignment num1 has 8 in the end and it should be printed by command print, and if it doesn't just print nothing.

```
import re

def x():
    num1 = 5894652138
    vav = re.match(r'[8]''$', num1)
    print vav   
x()
```

Comment: `re` is overkill. Cast `num1` to a `str` object and test that: `if str(num1).endswith('8')': print str(num1)` or some such.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It *"expected string or buffer"* but you're passing it an integer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use *re* here.
To check the last digit in decimal number, you should use the modulos with 10:

```
num1 = 5894652138
if num1 % 10 == 8:
    print num1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the answer as always is simple.

Answer (score -1):

```
def x():
    num1 = 5894652138
    num2 = str(num1)
    if (num2.endswith("8")):
        print num1
```

you could do this to see if 8 is at the end.